# Pass a file as a parameter in two Python Scripts

Tags: python, xml, parameters

New Python'er has a question *"hand raised"*.

I have two Python Scripts and a XML file. "mysecondpython.py" needs to call "myfirstpython.py" with a parameter of "data.xml" so that it can write something in, which then returns a file.

From command-line, I should type `python mysecondpython.py` and it should be viola! But I got no cigars. What is this new python'er doing wrong?

**myfirstpython.py**

```
import xml.etreeElementTree as et

def allmytrees(file):
    dest_tree = et.parse(file)
    dest_root = dest_tree.getroot()

def inserter():
    dest_root.insert(0, "hello world")

def printer():
    dest_tree.write('out.xml', xml_declaration=True, encoding='utf-8')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    allmytrees(file)
    inserter()
    printer()
```

**mysecondpython.py**

```
import myfirstpython

def callingscripts(file)
    callpython = myfirstpython(file)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    file = "data.xml"
    callingscripts(file)
```

**data.xml**

```
<root>
    <nothing-here>123</nothing-here>
</root>
```

*I'm in tears.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you import a file, it's `__name__` does not `== "__main__"`.

In fact, the statement `if __name__ == "__main__":` is specifically designed to say "am I the program that is running, or am I being imported (in which case don't do this stuff)"

You need to write a function in myfirstpython.py, and call it from mysecondpython.py

Comment: I'm still not sure what you mean. I was told I need to have the `if __name__ == "__main__":` in myfirstpython.py. mysecondpython.py is suppose to be the "main" program that passes the file to the myfirstpython.py.

Comment: You need that statement in myfirstpython _only if_ you intend to run myfirstpython from the command line.   The body of that statement is what will get run when you do so.   This is the _only_ time that body will get run.   However, in the case you are describing here, you are running mysecondpython from the command line.   Therefore, the stuff you put inside that block in myfirstpython is not getting run.

Answer (score 0):

Try moving the stuff in myfirstpython.py's `__main__` into a function:

```
def run(file):
    allmytrees(file)
    inserter()
    printer()
```

Then you can call it form mysecondpython.py:

`myfirstpython.run('data.xml')`